# How to filter out array(s) and its value(s) when a duplicate id is found

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, filter, reduce

How can I remove or filter out the succeeding array(s) and its/their value(s) if a duplicate `id` is found from the first/previous array? Just for example:

```
const a1 = ["id1", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
      a2 = ["id2", "y", "z", "w", "v"],
      a3 = ["id3", "k", "j", "i", "f"],
      a4 = ["m", "n", "o", "p", "id2"],
      a5 = [1, 2, "id1", 3, 4]
```

Since the `id1` is also found in `a5` and  `id2` in `a4`. So remove/ filter out those entire arrays that contain the duplicate `id1, id2, id3...id(n)` regardless of their different values and just keep the first array where the unique `id` first shows. So, the expected output of the above-example is:

```
           [
            ["id1", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
            ["id2", "y", "z", "w", "v"],
            ["id3", "k", "j", "i", "f"]
           ]
```

Comment: what do you mean with *"remove"*? from what? please add your try.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Removing variables is not a thing. Are you really talking about the output being **JavaScript code**??

Comment: @NinaScholz below somehow answered my question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the arrays in an array and filter by using an object as hash table.

```js
const
    data = [["id1", "b", "c", "d", "e"], ["id2", "y", "z", "w", "v"], ["id3", "k", "j", "i", "f"], ["m", "n", "o", "p", "id2"], [1, 2, "id1", 3, 4]],
    seen = {},
    result = data.filter(a => {
        const id = a.find(v => v.toString().startsWith('id'));
        if (seen[id]) return;
        return seen[id] = true;
    });

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This works good..What about your are dealing  with  multiple ids that do not contain  or starts with a an "id" string. Just for  example ("12345, 23456, 34567, etc")?

Comment: what is an id of it?

Comment: No worries. it seems your answer is working fine! I tested it with different ids that are all integer and works perfectly! I'm all set now.